# How to redirect in Safari on the latest iOS, Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios

I've literally went through 100 anwsers from StackOverflow and cannot seem to get my page to redirect anything using Javascript. Is there a new fix to this? 
The code i'm using is in the example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
getLocation();
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(redirectToPosition);






    } else { 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function redirectToPosition(position) {


var isAndroid = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/android/ig);
        var targetUrl = 'distributor.php?lat2='+position.coords.latitude+'&lon2='+position.coords.longitude;
        window.location = targetUrl;

if(!isAndroid) {
    var doc = window.document,
        ifr = doc.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.src = targetUrl;
    ifr.style.cssText = 'display:none;';
    doc.body.appendChild(ifr);
} else {
  var targetUrl = 'distributor.php?lat2='+position.coords.latitude+'&lon2='+position.coords.longitude;
        window.location = targetUrl;
}

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

No matter what I try to change it to. Doesn't redirect on iPhone/iPad iOS 11.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem ?
Here is the link to which the code originates. [USTarp](https://ustarp.com/Modules/)

Once the link is clicked it should redirect the user to the "Distributor.php" with latitude/longitude variables.

```
Tested:
    Redirection iFrame
    window.location
    window.location.href
    window.location.assign()
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.href = targetUrl` and `window.location.assign(targetUrl)`? If so, it would be helpful to update the question body to reflect what you've already tested.

Comment: Is your page under HTTPS? In specification, it only works in Secure HTTP: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation. Also, there must be a better way than using `iframe`, right?

Comment: Yes it is HTTPS! But i've tried 1,000 different ways. Nothing.

Comment: Have you connected to Safari Developer console (use USB cable to connect to Mac to view, assuming you're using Mac)? Any error / warning shown?

Comment: I'm not using a Mac. I've just tested on various iOS devices and can't seem to get it to redirect on anything newer.